# java virtual machine launcher Error: A jni error has occurred

Tags: java, virtual, launcher

I made a little program, so i built it and ran it on my pc and it worked. I took the .jar file and I ran it in other pc, but in others pc my program is not working and show this msg "java virtual machine launcher Error: A JNI error has occurred" I looked in the internet but all the questions and answers that I found where made for similiar isues but differnt, becase in their cases their softwares could'nt ran in their owns machines. in my case, my machine ran my software, and also this is happening with all my projects (i'm using netbeans).

## My PC:

[image]

## On other PC:

[image]

### Text from Screenshot

```
Title:  Java Virtual Machine Launcher
Icon:   Red and white "X" error icon.
Text:   Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again.
Button: Aceptar

Title:  Java Virtual Machine Launcher
Icon:   Red and white "X" error icon.
Text:   A Java Exception has occurred.
Button: Aceptar
```

Comment: I guess it is java version problem.  java version of both  computers. 
You can check version with java -version in command line.

Comment: [i got this](https://ibb.co/G9f6y4x)  both have the same version

Answer (score 1):

One reason can be that you have installed a 32-bit Java on 64-bin OS. To check that, open console and run command

```
java -version
```

This will show basic info about JRE including if it is 32-bit or 64-bit. If it is 32-bit, uninstall it and install 64-bit version.

Comment: @Angelgce: The 2nd screen shows that it is a 64-bit JRE which is OK. Then 1st one shows it is a 32-bit JRE. Remove it and install 64-bit JRE.

Answer (score 0):

i solve it installing JDK in the other computers ... :( idk'n why those computers didn't work with JRE